# Will I be able to use Cycles renerder with Gigabyte Gddr5 GT1030 2gb graphics card in Blender 3D 2.9 atleast for a basic projects

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, graphics, blender

Will I be able to use Cycles renerder with Gddr5 GT1030 2gb graphics card in Blender 3D 2.9 atleast for a basic projects with Dell with i3 2120 cpu.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html The 1030 doesn't appear on NVidia's list, linked from there.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

That would be very slow. I don't know about the GDDR5 version but I have the DDR4 version of the GT 1030 and whenever I try to do blender render on it, it renders really slow, it feels slower than my laptop's 5th gen Intel CPU.